# hide plusone button after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus-one

I want to hide google's +1 button after the user clicks on it using jQuery; this is the code I'm using but it seems it's not functioning properly:

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("#button").click(function()
  {
    $(".HIDE").hide();
  });

  return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="HIDE">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
  <g:plusone size="small" class="plusone"></g:plusone>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show the rendered HTML?

Comment: thats everything ?,oh the button is inside an iframe rendered by the g:plusone tag

Comment: Is `</g:plusone>` in the HTML received by the browser?

Comment: What's that `return false;});` doing hanging out there?

Comment: @lonesomeday not sure what you mean by received,@Dave removed it but still not working as

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [+1 tag `callback` parameter](http://code.google.com/apis/+1button/#plusonetag-parameters) to fire the hide function. There's probably a better way to select the +1 button but this works for the purpose of a demo.

```
<g:plusone size="tall" callback="poHide"></g:plusone>
<script src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<script>function poHide(){ $("#___plusone_0").fadeOut(); }</script>
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/Gju6T](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/Gju6T/)**

Comment: your code works like charm !!!,can i use the $.get function too ?will test and come back

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need, but put it at the end of your page just above `</body>`

```
$('g\\:plusone').live('click',function (){
   $(this).remove();
});
```

**ELSE 
try this...**

```
$('iframe').contents().find('#plusone').live('click',function (){
       $(this).remove();
    });
```

**orrr**

```
<script>
function mycall(str){
 console.log(str);
 //$(str).hide();//???
}
</script>
<g:plusone size="small" class="plusone" callback="mycall"></g:plusone>
```

Comment: there is an atribute called `callback="" `

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the HTML5 equivalent syntax:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="standard" data-count="true"></div>
```

All in all, the rendered HTML will be the thing to look at.

Comment: its still the same and i'm trying to hide element by class, so no difference

Answer (score 0):

The button is rendered into an iframe you don't have access to. The `<g:plusone>` tag is replaced by JS with an iframe and you cannot observe this button via jQuery, for example with live() or bind(). You have to use the API of the button which can be found [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/+1button/).
There you find the option "callback" you could use like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
      {"parsetags": "explicit"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Call the API method after the page loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
   gapi.plusone.render("HIDE",
       {"size": "standard", "count": "true", "callback" : "hideTheButton"});
});
// Method to remove the element
function hideTheButton() {
   $("#HIDE").hide();
}
</script>
<div id="HIDE">
      <g:plusone></g:plusone>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm, I edited the code and used the "HIDE" id instead of "content"