# how to hide the google +1 button?

Tags: html, google-plus-one

I have a google +1 button in a div which is supposed to be initially hidden and should change visibility on a click event. Everything else in the div works fine but for some reason the button won't inherit the div rules and it stays permanently visible:

```
<div id="sharethisdish"> 
    ...
        <g:plusone size="small" count="false" ></g:plusone>
</div>
```

I've tried giving the button its own styling in the html as well as giving it an id and defining the styling in my css page but it doesn't seem to follow any rules. Does anyone know  how to change its visibility?

Comment: Does this answer it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254100/hide-plusone-button-after-click

Comment: Check this post once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254100/hide-plusone-button-after-click

Comment: I just noticed that the title and the actual question seem to contradict one another.  Are you trying to hide it or show it?  The title says hide but I took the question to mean that you wanted to make it always visible.

Comment: hmm thanks but I don't think so. I think in that question they're trying to hide the button after it's been called by redefining its behavior on callback, unless i'm missing something...

Answer (score 0):

If the hiding/showing is being done onClick then chances are that it is applying the style inline.  Which means the inline style will override the one set in your css file.

You could use `!important` and I believe that should override the style being applied on click.

Comment: I tried adding a !important to the visibility property in the styling for the div and wrapping the button in a span with a class whose visibility was defined as visibility: inherit !important but it didn't seem to work. Is there some other way that you'd recommend that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't know the format of the html for that button but the `!important` would have to the button itself, not an element which it is within.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

HTML:

```
<div id="sharethisdish">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<g:plusone size="tall" callback="g_click_function"></g:plusone>
```

JS:

```
var d = document.getElementById("sharethisdish");
d.style.display = "none";
```

Now make onclick event that would make d.style.display = "inline";